# Using jquery how to automatically remove the first blank option in dropdown list if it depended on another choice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 dropdown lists. First one has id "q1" , second "q2" and the third "q3" .The options for "q2" appear when the user selects an option from "q1" and "q3" options appears when the user selects an option from "q2".
The question is how to delete the first blank option from "q2" when user selects an option from "q1" and also how to delete the first option in "q3 when user select an option from "q2".
I Tried this code, it delete the first blank option from "q2" but after I select from "q2" I need it delete after I select from "q1" to appear direct without the blank option.

```
$("#q1 select").change(function(){      
$('#q1 select option').filter(function() {
  return !this.value || $.trim(this.value).length == 0;
})
.remove();

$('#q2 select option').filter(function() {
  return !this.value || $.trim(this.value).length == 0;
})
.remove();

$('#q3 select option').filter(function() {
  return !this.value || $.trim(this.value).length == 0;
})
.remove();
});

 $("#q2 select").change(function(){    
 $('#q2 select option').filter(function() {
  return !this.value || $.trim(this.value).length == 0;
})
.remove();

$('#q3 select option').filter(function() {
  return !this.value || $.trim(this.value).length == 0;
})
.remove();
});
```

Comment: Why you downvote the anwser? It isn't what do you need?

Answer (score 0):

What about this code:

```js
$(function(){
  $("#q1").change(function(){
   if($("#q2 option")[0].value == "")
   $("#q2 option")[0].remove();
  });
  $("#q2").change(function(){
  if($("#q3 option")[0].value == "")
   $("#q3 option")[0].remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<p>
<select id="q1">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="volvo">1</option>
  <option value="saab">2</option>
  <option value="opel">3</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>
<select id="q2">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="volvo">4</option>
  <option value="saab">5</option>
  <option value="opel">6</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>
<select id="q3">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="volvo">7</option>
  <option value="saab">8</option>
  <option value="opel">9</option>
</select>
</p>
</body>
```